$\pi\colon X \to X/G$ is a covering map

This is a page of "Basic Topology" by Armstrong. Here in sketch proof it states that $\{g(U)\:|\:g \in G\}$ is decomposition of $U$ but before that it sates that $g(U)$ and $U$ are disjoint. I'm so confused how is this possible?

In particular $e\in G$ so that $U=eU\in \{gU : g\in G\}$. We only require $U\cap gU = \emptyset$ for $g\in G\setminus\{e\}$. Now
$$
\pi^{-1}(V) = \pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = \bigcup_{g\in G} gU
$$
as a disjoint union as otherwise $z\in gU\cap hU$ would imply $g^{-1}z \in U\cap g^{-1}hU$ so that $g^{-1}h=e$, i.e. $h=g$. By definition of the quotient topology $\pi\colon X\to X/G$ is continuous and one can further show that its an open mapping. By construction of $V$ we also see that $\pi|_{gU}^V \colon gU \to V$ is a bijection and thus a homeomorphism.

I see nowhere in the quoted passage where it says (incorrectly) that $\{g(U) \mid g \in G\}$ is a decomposition of $U$.
Instead what it (correctly) says to do in the last paragraph is to "set $V=\pi(U)$" and to "take $\{g(U) \mid g \in G\}$ for the family $\{U_\alpha\}$", and then it leaves implicit that with this choice for the family $\{U_\alpha\}$ the earlier statement is true that the family $\{(U_\alpha)\} \, \bigl($which has been set equal to $\{g(U) \mid g \in G\}\bigr)$ is a decomposition of $\pi^{-1}(V)$ into pairwise disjoint open sets.
